# Keep image hover effect when hovering the text in front of it

Tags: html, css

When hovering over the text (inside an image), the scale property is not applyed (it scales back to original), but when I'm hovering only over the image it works.

```css
.gallery {
  width:500px;
}
.gallery-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.gallery-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
.gallery-img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  filter: brightness(0.4);
}

.gallery-img-text {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  visibility: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.gallery-item:hover .gallery-img-text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <figure class="gallery-item">
    <img
      class="gallery-img"
      src="https://live.staticflickr.com/2462/3934247179_f29557d66a_z.jpg"
      alt="photo of beautifully arranged food"
    />
    <div class="gallery-img-text">
      <p>Omelette</p>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

I would like to keep the effect even I hover the text. How can I do it ?

Comment: Please note, a proper [mre] of our issue needs to be contained directly inside your question. Please do not show only parts of the relevant code here, and the rest only on some external platform.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback , I'll keep it in mind from onwards , I'm new to stack overflow , so still learning all the rules and standards .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you hover the text instead of the image, you need to select the container and apply your style on the image. Try `.gallery-item:hover .gallery-img{}` instead of `.gallery-img:hover{}`

```css
.gallery {
  width:500px;
}
.gallery-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.gallery-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
.gallery-item:hover .gallery-img{
  transform: scale(1.2);
  filter: brightness(0.4);
}
.gallery-img-text {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  visibility: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
.gallery-item:hover .gallery-img-text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <figure class="gallery-item">
    <img class="gallery-img"
    src="https://live.staticflickr.com/2462/3934247179_f29557d66a_z.jpg"
    alt="photo of beautifully arranged food" />
    <div class="gallery-img-text">
      <p>Omelette</p>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on your `gallery-img-text` class:

```
.gallery-item:hover .gallery-img-text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```